# Django NoReverseMatch in production; works fine on localhost

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

So I recently moved my app to PythonAnywhere. The URL dispatchers were working fine on localhost. After moving to PythonAnywhere, I keep getting this error:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'blockdata' with arguments '('nameofdistrict',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rmgcovid/<districtid>']
```

districtid variable is a string and therefore my app's url.py file also represent it as a slug:

```
 url('<slug:districtid>',views.blockdata,name='blockdata')
```

Here is the part of my template that causes the app to crash and throw the error mentioned above:

```
<form action='{% url "blockdata" districtid %}' method="POST">
```

My views are ok because if I pass 200 as HttpResponse, it shows up that. But with this form action, it is unable to match the URL.

I have tried solving this for a good 10 hours now. I would appreciate any help at this moment. Why is it working on local host fine but now on PythonAnywhere it crashes?

Here is my project's URL snapshot as well:

```
url(r'^customurl/',include('myappname.urls'))
```

the customurl is replaced with my specific url

Comment: You should be using path not url to use that url syntax? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path

Comment: How on earth did I miss that?! Thank you so much! @IainShelvington